# Message: Object of class CI_DB_postgre_result could not be converted to string

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql

```
$this->db->query("select tech_voc from accreditation where type='accredit_B' AND major_field_id=1 AND tech_voc=0");
```

this query results to 0

But when I put the query to $query and tried to echo it. I get

```
Message: Object of class CI_DB_postgre_result could not be converted to string.
```

And then I tried to see the data type of $query and it says Object.

Well,I  want to put this $query to an if statement like

```
if($query==0){
//code here
}
```

Is there anyway I can do it? Some says $query should be converted to string first then to an integer. But I don't know how.

Comment: You want to check if the query is executed ?

Comment: I want to put the query in an if statement. Like if the query is equal to 0, I can execute some codes.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the string from the row that is returned in the query result. You should be able to do it like this presuming there is only ever one result returned. You should be checking for that as well in case multiple rows come back.

```
$query = $this->db->query("select tech_voc from accreditation where type='accredit_B' AND major_field_id=1 AND tech_voc=0");
$tech_voc = $query->row('tech_voc');
if($tech_voc == 0)
{
//code here
}
```

As you are using codeigniter for this there is no need to write the query in a verbose way as you have. You should use [active record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) to make this easier and more maintainable.